# Access Google Drive API via Identity Federation

Tags: authentication, google-drive-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm working on an application that needs to access a Google Drive folder. The application's authentication mechanism is powered by Azure AD. After reviewing the official documentation, I found that gaining access to the Google Drive API can be achieved using either OAuth or a service account. However, I couldn't find any mention of using identity federation for authentication.

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to accomplish this integration using identity federation instead of relying on OAuth or a service account. The documentation from both Azure AD and Google Drive doesn't seem to cover this specific scenario.

So far, I've explored the various authentication options provided by the Google Drive API, including OAuth and service account, but none of them seem to fit my exact scenario, which requires utilizing Azure AD authentication. I've attempted to follow the tutorial provided in the link below, which outlines the integration between Google Apps and Azure AD, but it doesn't address the identity federation aspect.

Tutorial Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/google-apps-tutorial

I'm curious to know if there's a way to achieve this integration using Azure AD identity federation and the Google Drive API, or if there's any recommended alternative approach to handling this scenario.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!